# JPA EclipseLink PostgreSQL Insert java.time.LocalDate as java.sql.Date inserts wrong date

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, localdate

I'm getting a really strange behavior. I'm creating an Entity that has LocalDate fields, and inserting in the database, but the values in the database, are changed in some situations. This is the SQL it's logged with the debugger:

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2016-11-19 21:31:57.979
--ClientSession(1809129176)--Connection(1261635736)
--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])
--INSERT INTO vcc_task (creator_user, execution_end_time, execution_start_time, last_edit_time, last_edit_user, server_name, state, thread_name, version, task_type, cc_service_id, vcc, start_time, end_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [user@vccModel1, null, null, 2016-11-20 00:31:46.016, user@vccModel1, , 0, , 1, 0, c1, vccModel1, 2017-05-06, 2017-05-07]
```

Note the "**2017-05-06, 2017-05-07**". 
But if I query postgreSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM vcc_task
```

[image]

Other tests I wrote doesn't behave wrong. They save the correct date in the database. So, I'm pretty confuse.

If I query the database using the same EntityManager I used to store the taskEntity, I get an entity with the correct date. But if I query using a different EntityManager, I get the date from the database, that is one day before the correct date. That makes sense because the EM is returning from its cache. But I still don't understand who is transforming the Date, and why sometimes it does, and sometimes it doesn't.

For example, the following test pass using both LocalDate constructors:

```
  // private final LocalDate startTime = LocalDate.parse("2017-05-06");
  // private final LocalDate endTime = LocalDate.parse("2017-06-06");
  private final LocalDate startTime = Instant.parse("2017-05-06T00:00:00Z").atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
  private final LocalDate endTime = Instant.parse("2017-06-06T00:00:00Z").atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();

  em = MyEntityManager.getEntityManager();
  final TaskDT tdt = new TaskDT(taskType, ccService, startTime, endTime, userName);
  t1 = new TaskEntity(userName, vcc, tdt);
  PersistLogic.persist(em, t1);
  em.close();

  em = MyEntityManager.getEntityManager();
  final TaskEntity t2 = em.find(TaskEntity.class, tid);
  em.close();

  Assert.assertNotNull(t2, "Task does exist");      
  Assert.assertEquals(t2.getVersion(), 1, "Resource Version");
  Assert.assertEquals(t2.getLastEditUser(), userName, "Resource Version");

  Assert.assertEquals(t2.getId().getVcc(), vcc, "getVcc");
  Assert.assertEquals(t2.getId().getTaskType(), taskType, "getTaskType");
  Assert.assertEquals(t2.getId().getCcService(), ccService, "getCcService");
  Assert.assertEquals(t2.getId().getStartTime(), startTime, "getStartTime");
  Assert.assertEquals(t2.getId().getEndTime(), endTime, "getEndTime");
  ...
```

[image]

The problem is happening when I create the Entity in the code:

```
// create the task
final LocalDate taskFromD = toLocalDate(tmpFrom);
final LocalDate taskToD = toLocalDate(tmpTo);
final TaskDT taskDT = new TaskDT(taskType, ccServiceName, taskFromD, taskToD, userName);
final TaskEntity newTask = new TaskEntity(userName, vccName, taskDT);

PersistLogic.persist(em, newTask);
```

It looks the same, but behaves different.

**UPDATE**

This is how I convert an Instant to LocalDate to pass to the Entity:

```
private static LocalDate toLocalDate(Instant i) {
   return i.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
}
```

This is the way I convert LocalDate to Date and back:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: `LocalDate` is implicitly with respect to the local time zone, whatever that happens to be.  `Date` is the old Java API analog of the newer Java `Instant` which internally is in UTC.  Are you able to convert your `LocalDate` instances to `Instant`s?  And, if so, do they exhibit the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: I Updated with the code that converts LocalDate to Date and back. The test case that pass, uses LocalDate that are constructed by parse a string. But in the code, that fails, I create the LocalDate from an Instant. Could that be the difference?

Comment: The issue is produced because I have this setting: 
      TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Comment: If I remove that setting, the date is correctly stored in the database.

Comment: The problem I have is that I need to keep the setting to store and read Instant objects correctly.

Comment: Your problem is almost certainly related to the time zone, which isn't being accounted for by your code.  Although pure calendar dates don't have time values and are supposed to be constant everywhere, time zones can matter when a calendar date from one zone has to be internally represented.  If the local time is 10P in Central Standard Time, then the date 7-Sept-2015 locally is 8-Sept-2015 in England *at the same instant*. `LocalDate` instances don't have an associated time, but `Date` instances always do.

Comment: Well, my intention is managing everything as UTC datetimes, and format the dates in the Timezone the user wants just in the frontend of the App. So, my backend only manages UTC datetimes. That is the objective. Sadly is not so easy as I expected. The default behavior of JVM, JPA, JDBC, etc, use local server datetime. It's like swimming against the current.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the call Date.valueOf(locDate) in the method convertToDatabaseColumn(), the instant generated here is the midnight of this date **in the default time zone of your system**.

Comment: No, that is not the problem. In the convertToDatabaseColumn method I'm converting direct from java.time.LocalDate to java.sql.Date. I'm not using the Instant class. And when debugging , the java.time.LocalDate is correctly converted to sql.Date. It's like a framework issue. I had to decide to use Instant instead of LocalDate. With Instant class I don't conversion problems.

Comment: LocalDate does not have relation to a time zone and java.sql.Date does. If you perform this convertion on the system with the time zone set to UTC+4, then the result will be 0:00 of this day in UTC+4 and it's equal to 20:00 of the previous day in UTC+0 - just due to the nature of time zones.